# Does every PHP code snippet inside the <?php> tag have its own variable scope?

Tags: php, variables, scope, tags, code-snippets

If yes is there any way to access a var defined in another PHP code snippet tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, they don't. Separate `<?php ?>` tags share the same variable scope. You can access any variable declared from any scope:

```
<?php $foo = 4; ?>
<?php echo $foo; /* will echo 4 */ ?>
```

The only scoping notion in PHP exists for functions or methods. To use a global variable in a function or a method, you must use the `$GLOBALS` array, or a `global $theVariableINeed;` declaration inside your function.

Comment: Re: "The only scoping notion in PHP exists for functions or methods", PHP 5.3 and namespaces kind of turn that statement on its ear.

Answer (score 1):

No, by default all files share the same scope in PHP. The only scoping you get is by using classes or functions.

Answer (score 1):

Variable scope in PHP doesn't work like that.

Variable score is working in classes and functions. For example:

```
<?php $a = 10 ?>

<?php echo $a; ?>
```

This will work.

However:

```
<?php
$a = 10;

function get_a(){
  echo $a;
}
?>
```

This one will not work. It's either not showing $a value or NOTICE level error (depending on your configuration)

For more info, you can [see this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the parts of the script that AREN'T inside `<?php ?>` as equivalent to an echo statement, except without any interpolation of variables, quotes, etc. - only `<?php ?>`. So for instance, you can even do something like this:

```
<?php
if (42)
{
?>
    This will only be output if 42 is true.
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Note: I'm not saying this is a good idea to do, it just illustrates my point well.

Comment: This feature is extremely useful for automatically generated code, but I'd rather not read or write that myself.

Comment: So gross. But hey PHP was way ahead of JSX :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<php
$a = '111';
?>
```

and

```
<php
echo $a
?>
```

in the same page, it will output 111, meaning, it recognizes the variables from the first PHP snippet.